# Does aws codebuild support asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Trying to build and publish asp.net(Not Core) application using aws CodeBuild.
Does aws codebuild support traditional .net application?
Gone through older thread on stackoverflow but still not clear.

Tried with sample asp.net application on aws Codebuild, it's able to build but not able to Publish and get all the artifacts i need to deploy on IIS.

Anyone tried aws codebuild with asp.net application?

This question sounds silly but having hard time publishing asp.net application using codebuild. Tried most of the MSbuild command given for this online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CodeBuild supports .NET Framework applications, please refer to the following link which is a tutorial:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-windows.html

... and the following blog post:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/creating-ci-cd-pipelines-for-asp-net-4-x-with-aws-codepipeline-and-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

*Excerpt of configuring CodeBuild project:*

> 1. After choosing Next, select AWS CodeBuild as the build provider.
> 2. Select your region, then choose Create project, which will open CodeBuild in another browser window.
> 3. In the CodeBuild window, you can optionally assign your build project a name and description.
> 4. Under Environment, select the Custom image option, and select Windows as the environment type.
> 5. For building ASP.NET 4.x (.NET Framework) web projects, it’s easiest to start out with Microsoft’s .NET Framework SDK docker image,
>      which they host on their registry. Select Other registry, and use
>      mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:[version-tag] as the registry
>      URL. Replace version-tag with the .NET framework version. For .NET
>      Framework 4.x, the most likely options are 4.7.1, 4.7.2 or 4.8. This
>      example uses mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2.

Comment: Able to resolve this issue. default windows build agent does not support asp.net framework. It supports only .net core. So we need to use a custom docker image to build asp.net application.

Comment: @Nishant I've been stuck for 2 days  trying to create the publish of an 4.7.2 asp.net application with code build but it only makes a build and not a publish with the IIS files, I will try to setup a docker Image and try!! for now thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge